# Discrete range/interval in siunitx

Tags: siunitx, sirange

Using `siunitx`, I can type `$V = \SIrange[range-phrase=\text{ to },range-units=single]{100}{125}{\kilo\m\per\hour}$` to get

[image]

However, numerically speaking, I have to specify the step of the range in order to know exactly each speed value I will do my calculations at.

Therefore, I would like to understand how to create a command, e.g. `\SIsteps`, where it accepts the following arguments:

`<start>`,

`<step>` (optional and its default is `1`) it can be integer or float,

`<size>` (optional) it is the total number of the elements in the range/interval

`<end>`, and

`<unit>`.

So, for example, all the following codes should have the same output of

[image]

`The speed range is $V = \SIsteps[step=5]{100}{125}{\km}$`

`The speed range is $V = \SIsteps[size=6]{100}{}{\km}$`

`The speed range is $V = \SIsteps[size=6]{}{125}{\km}$`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math,siunitx}
\sisetup{
    load-configurations = abbreviations,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\hspace{-0.5ex}}\cdot{\hspace{-0.5ex}}}
}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}
The speed range is $V = \left\{100,105,\ldots,125\right\}~\si{\km\per\hour}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the output contain ellipsis dots? If so, what should be the format?

Comment: @egreg I think this is the typical mathematical notation. You probably know better than me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macro `\SIsteps` has

1. an optional argument for options to be passed to `\num`
2. a mandatory argument with options for the steps
3. an optional argument with options for `\si`
4. a mandatory argument for the unit

As you requested, the default step is 1, but it can be specified either in the options or (following normal scope rules) with `\stepsetup`.

The keys are

- `start` to set the starting point
- `end` to set the end point
- `step` to set the step
- `size` to set the number of items to show
- `full` to specify we want a full display of the values (default false)
- `sep` to specify the separator between items (default comma)

You have better to specify two keys among `start`, `end` and `size`, but don't specify all three of them.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xfp}

\sisetup{
    load-configurations = abbreviations,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\cdot}}
}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { diaa/steps }
 {
  start .fp_set:N   = \l__diaa_steps_start_fp,
  start .initial:n  = -\c_inf_fp,
  end   .fp_set:N   = \l__diaa_steps_end_fp,
  end   .initial:n  = \c_inf_fp,
  step  .fp_set:N   = \l__diaa_steps_step_fp,
  step  .initial:n  = 1,
  size  .int_set:N  = \l__diaa_steps_size_int,
  full  .bool_set:N = \l__diaa_steps_full_bool,
  full  .initial:n  = false,
  full  .default:n  = true,
  sep   .tl_set:N   = \l__diaa_steps_sep_tl,
  sep   .initial:n  = {,},
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\SIsteps}{O{}mO{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { diaa/steps } { #2 }
  \int_compare:nT { \l__diaa_steps_size_int > 0 }
   {% size has been specified
    \fp_compare:nTF { \l__diaa_steps_end_fp = \c_inf_fp }
     {% end has not been specified
      \fp_set:Nn \l__diaa_steps_end_fp
       {
        \l__diaa_steps_start_fp + (\l__diaa_steps_size_int-1)*\l__diaa_steps_step_fp
       }
     }
     {% start has not been specified
      \fp_set:Nn \l__diaa_steps_start_fp
       {
        \l__diaa_steps_end_fp - (\l__diaa_steps_size_int-1)*\l__diaa_steps_step_fp
       }
     }
   }
  \ensuremath
   {
    \{
    \bool_if:NTF \l__diaa_steps_full_bool
     {% full display
      \fp_step_inline:nnnn
       { \l__diaa_steps_start_fp } % start
       { \l__diaa_steps_step_fp } % step
       { \l__diaa_steps_end_fp - \l__diaa_steps_step_fp } % end
       {
        \num[#1]{ \fp_eval:n { ##1 } } \l__diaa_steps_sep_tl
       }
       \num[#1]{ \fp_eval:n { \l__diaa_steps_end_fp } }
     }
     {% short display
      \num[#1]{ \fp_eval:n { \l__diaa_steps_start_fp } }
      \l__diaa_steps_sep_tl
      \num[#1]{ \fp_eval:n { \l__diaa_steps_start_fp + \l__diaa_steps_step_fp } }
      \l__diaa_steps_sep_tl
      \dots\l__diaa_steps_sep_tl
      \num[#1]{ \fp_eval:n { \l__diaa_steps_end_fp } }
     }
    \}
    \,\si[#3]{#4}
   }
  \group_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\stepsetup}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { diaa/steps } { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The speed range is $V = \SIsteps{step=5,start=100,end=125}{\km\per\hour}$

The speed range is $V = \SIsteps{size=6,start=100}{\km\per\hour}$ % step is one

The speed range is $V = \SIsteps{size=6,start=100,step=5}{\km\per\hour}$

\stepsetup{step=5}

The speed range is $V = \SIsteps{size=6,end=125}{\km\per\hour}$

The speed range is $V = \SIsteps{size=6,end=125,full,sep={;}}{\km\per\hour}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The explicit `\,` between the brace and the unit might be `\l__siunitx_number_unit_product_tl`, but this is an internal of `siunitx` and it's bad practice to use it. This might possibly be offered as a user level token list in the future.

You can also add support for angles (but not minutes and seconds, for that you'd be charged a thousand times).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xfp}

\sisetup{
    load-configurations = abbreviations,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\cdot}}
}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { diaa/steps }
 {
  start .fp_set:N   = \l__diaa_steps_start_fp,
  start .initial:n  = -\c_inf_fp,
  end   .fp_set:N   = \l__diaa_steps_end_fp,
  end   .initial:n  = \c_inf_fp,
  step  .fp_set:N   = \l__diaa_steps_step_fp,
  step  .initial:n  = 1,
  size  .int_set:N  = \l__diaa_steps_size_int,
  full  .bool_set:N = \l__diaa_steps_full_bool,
  full  .initial:n  = false,
  full  .default:n  = true,
  sep   .tl_set:N   = \l__diaa_steps_sep_tl,
  sep   .initial:n  = {,},
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\SIsteps}{O{}mO{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \diaa_sisteps:nnnnNn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
                       \num 
                       { \l__siunitx_number_unit_product_tl \si[#3]{#4} }
  \group_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\anglesteps}{O{}mO{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \diaa_sisteps:nnnnNn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { }
                       \ang 
                       { }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \diaa_sisteps:nnnnNn
 {
  \keys_set:nn { diaa/steps } { #2 }
  \int_compare:nT { \l__diaa_steps_size_int > 0 }
   {% size has been specified
    \fp_compare:nTF { \l__diaa_steps_end_fp = \c_inf_fp }
     {% end has not been specified
      \fp_set:Nn \l__diaa_steps_end_fp
       {
        \l__diaa_steps_start_fp + (\l__diaa_steps_size_int-1)*\l__diaa_steps_step_fp
       }
     }
     {% start has not been specified
      \fp_set:Nn \l__diaa_steps_start_fp
       {
        \l__diaa_steps_end_fp - (\l__diaa_steps_size_int-1)*\l__diaa_steps_step_fp
       }
     }
   }
  \ensuremath
   {
    \{
    \bool_if:NTF \l__diaa_steps_full_bool
     {% full display
      \fp_step_inline:nnnn
       { \l__diaa_steps_start_fp } % start
       { \l__diaa_steps_step_fp } % step
       { \l__diaa_steps_end_fp - \l__diaa_steps_step_fp } % end
       {
        #5[#1]{ \fp_eval:n { ##1 } } \l__diaa_steps_sep_tl
       }
       #5[#1]{ \fp_eval:n { \l__diaa_steps_end_fp } }
     }
     {% short display
      #5[#1]{ \fp_eval:n { \l__diaa_steps_start_fp } }
      \l__diaa_steps_sep_tl
      #5[#1]{ \fp_eval:n { \l__diaa_steps_start_fp + \l__diaa_steps_step_fp } }
      \l__diaa_steps_sep_tl
      \fp_compare:nT
       { (\l__diaa_steps_end_fp-\l__diaa_steps_start_fp)/\l__diaa_steps_step_fp > 3 }
       { \dots\l__diaa_steps_sep_tl }
      #5[#1]{ \fp_eval:n { \l__diaa_steps_end_fp } }
     }
    \}
    #6
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\stepsetup}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { diaa/steps } { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The speed range is $V = \SIsteps{step=5,start=100,end=125}{\km\per\hour}$

The speed range is $V = \SIsteps{size=6,start=100}{\km\per\hour}$ % step is one

The speed range is $V = \SIsteps{size=6,start=100,step=5}{\km\per\hour}$

The speed range is $V = \SIsteps{size=6,start=84.37,step=5}{\km\per\hour}$

\stepsetup{step=5}

The speed range is $V = \SIsteps{size=6,end=125}{\km\per\hour}$

The speed range is $V = \SIsteps{size=6,end=125,full,sep={;}}{\km\per\hour}$

The speed range is $V = \SIsteps{step=5,start=20,end=30}{\km\per\hour}$

\stepsetup{step=1}

Angle ranges:

\anglesteps{step=5,start=100,end=125}

\anglesteps{size=6,start=100}

\anglesteps{size=6,start=100,step=5}

\anglesteps{size=6,start=84.37,step=5}

\stepsetup{step=5}

\anglesteps{size=6,end=125}

\anglesteps{size=6,end=125,full,sep={;}}

\anglesteps{step=5,start=20,end=30}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### UPDATE for `siunitx` version 3

The `load-configurations` option is no longer valid and the first code works the same as with version 2.

For the second code, replace `\l__siunitx_number_unit_product_tl` with `\l__siunitx_quantity_product_tl` (there seems to be no interface to it yet).

In addition `\si` should also become `\unit` and, for uniformity, `\SIsteps` should perhaps be renamed `\qtysteps`.

Comment: Great answer as usual :) Thanks for the addition of `full` key. It is great and helpful, especially in the small ranges.

Comment: Would you please provide another variant for a discrete range of angles? For example, another command or key can be defined to get an output same as `{\ang{100}, \ang{105}, ..., \ang{125}}`.

Comment: @Diaa Only integer angles? Or are you thinking to angles specified with minutes and seconds? In that case, I pass, sorry.

Comment: I meant integer angles.

Comment: @Diaa Added as requested.

Comment: Thanks for your generosity :D

Comment: I found an issue where `\anglesteps{step=5,start=20,end=30}` prints `\ldots` before the final value, however, `\ldots` should be printed where the total number of elements exceeds three up to my knowledge.

Comment: @Diaa Now it should be fixed: the dots are added only if the number of items is greater than three.

Comment: Should this answer be updated for `siunitx` version 3? I get errors now, and I suspect this code to be not compatible with the last version of siunitx. `Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...end_fp }}}\}\l__siunitx_number_unit_product_tl `

Comment: I see :) So, what should it be replaced with to have the same output?

Comment: @Diaa I added an update.